# Construct triangle given the circumcenter, incenter and the intersection point of the extension of one of the bisectors with the circumscribed circle.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Kiselev Planimetry ex.596. The question is the one on the title. Here is my progress so far:

Let $C$ be the circumcenter, $I$ the incenter and $D$ be the intersection point of the extension of one of the bisectors with the circumscribed circle.

1. Form the circumscribed circle (since we have $C, D$).
2. Connect $D, I$ with a line, find the intersection point with the circumscribed circle. This is a vertex of the triangle, call it $A$.
3. $OD$ is perpendicular to $BC$, since the arcs $BD$, $DC$ have the same length.

Given the above, we want to find a point (which will be $B$) that a) will lie on the arc $AD$, and b) $BI$ bisects the angle formed by BA, and the perpendicular to $OD$, dropped from $B$.

Can one provide a hint to continue from here, or any further idea?
Essentially this question has been asked before here [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215778/construction-based-on-circumcenter-and-incenter), but there was no (correct) answer.

Comment: There is some confusion between $O$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Apply Euker's theorem:

$d^2=R(R-2r)$

where d is distance between I (incenter) and O(circumcenter), R=OD is the radius of circle and r is the radius of inscribed circle.You foud vertex A Now draw inscribed circle. Draw two tangents from A on it. The intersection of these tangents with circle give B and C.

Comment: Nice hammer! I saw the proof of Euler's theorem: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/EulerIO.shtml and there it is shown that ID=IC, which immediately gives a way to construct the triangle.